# How to keep my screen responsive using grid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, styling, responsive

I'm working on small and very simple WPF application, BUT I'm having trouble with responsive stuffs, computer where I'm working at is like 22'' with full HD resolution and everything looks fine, let me post picture how it looks like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But when I run application on smaller monitor, my content also moves up, acctualy my datagrid and my textboxes somehow glue up to the header ( which has blue background). And it looks really bad on smaller devices. I'm working with grids and I thought that's right way, but probably I am doing something wrong..

So this is how it looks on smaller device and resolution:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And here is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">

      <!-- This is my main grid which is coming by default when I created this window -->

    <Grid>
      <!-- I created this grid, because soon I will put image to the left, as my logo, and few informations also, thats reason why I have column definition -->

        <Grid Height="65" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,60*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#0091EA"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

          <!-- This is big grid which is separated in two columns which fits on screen 80% of screen - left part 20% of screen right part -->
    <Grid Margin="0,50,0,0">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="0,80*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="0,20*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" BorderThickness="0,0,3,0" BorderBrush="#0091EA"/>

          <!-- Here are my text boxes, 6 of them, so I have 6 column definitions-->

        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,30*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,12*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,12*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,12*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,12*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0,10*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0,86*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0,04*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

           <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" BorderThickness="0,3,0,0" BorderBrush="#0091EA"/>

            <TextBox Height="40" Margin="15,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="6" MinHeight="200" Margin="15,-20,8,50" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="White" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Edit after Mark's answer:

XAML CODE:

```
<Window x:Class="xTouchPOS.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">

    <Grid>
   <!-- I created this grid, because soon I will put image to the left, as my logo, and few informations also, thats reason why I have column definition -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Reserved header space-->
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <!--Rest of space for textboxes and grid, etc.-->
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" />

     <!--My edit.Added one more grid to row 0 which will contain some things that I need like time, date, user which is currently using app-->

    <Grid Height="50" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,60*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0,10*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Stretch="Fill" Name="image2" Source="C:\Users\Tuca\Desktop\microsoft.logo.png" Width="135" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock  x:Name="lblTimeText"  Text="Time"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  FontSize="15" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <TextBlock  x:Name="lblTime" Text="labelTime" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0"  FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Arial"  />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock  Name="lblDateText" Text="Date" Margin="0" FontSize="15" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Arial" />
            <TextBlock  Name="lblDate"  Text="labelaDate" Margin="0" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Arial"  />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock  x:Name="lblOperater"  Text="User"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  FontSize="15" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <TextBlock  x:Name="lblOperaterText" Text="Tony Montana" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0"  FontSize="16" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Arial"  />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock  x:Name="lblNumber"  Text="Ordinal number."  Margin="0,0,40,0"  FontSize="15" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            <TextBlock  x:Name="lblNumber" Text="0014" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0"  FontSize="16" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Arial"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <!--header section-->


    <!-- This is big grid which is separated in two columns which fits on screen 80% of screen - left part 20% of screen right part -->
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Space for Textboxes - left to auto so that it is not overconstrained, but does
            not take up too much space-->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <!--Datagrid gets the remainder of the space-->
            <RowDefinition />
            <!--This is the space allowed for the bottom border-->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Reserved 80% of remaining space for text/grid-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            <!--This is the space allowed for the right border-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <!--This is the 20% of remaining space-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--textbox section-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--you only had 8 definitions, but 6 boxes... not sure what is intended-->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Height="40" Margin="15,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
        </Grid>
        <!--grid element-->
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="200" Margin="15,0,8,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="White" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
        <!--right border element-->
        <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" Width="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />

        <!--bottom border element-->
        <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" Height="3" Grid.Row="2" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

So mate take a look I edited header, is that right way? To add one more grid with stackpanels, and how could I add copyright and stuffs at the bottom, shouldn't I treat it as one more row which will be very small by heigh for exaple 20px? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: you may have to implement some code to determine the type of monitor and it's size etc.. and dynamically set your screen look and feel based on the size of the monitor it's running on..

Comment: @MethodMan I believe I did something wrong. Because working with wpf grids should gave me responsive app, I will try to find out whats happening, and that will be my last solution to calculate screen size and to set my screen look based on the monitor it'r running on... but thanks for comment :)

Comment: You've got some absolute values `TextBox Height="40"` for example. In general, always avoid that and use relative values .

Comment: @Pikoh I tried everything, even if I put Height="Auto" to my textboxes that even looks worse :)

Comment: Updated header looks pretty good.  I would consider making column 0 * width and the other sections Auto width - then use margin on the stackpanels to keep the spacing.  This will keep those panels of data to the right of the application without the space between them changing as you resize the window.

Comment: Regarding copyright... it is effectively a footer, so you would treat it similarly to the header... make a new row definition at whatever height you deem appropriate.  the * height of the 2nd row will use all available leftover space.

Comment: I'm sorry you grabbed my code when you did... I had made an update to it that better laid out the 80/20 split of the main section and removed the comment about the textbox column definitions - that was my copy/paste error.

Comment: @MarkW Hmmm, thanks a lot sir! and about copyright I should do something like this <Grid Height="50" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></Grid> ? If so, I tried that and places label between grid tags but label is somehow exactly on my blue line its not below it.. as I would like to make it..

Comment: Go ahead and check the update to my answer.  You'll get it... just keep working at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the right idea - use grids for layout... You just need some more experience with it.  Pikoh is correct in the comment about "hard coded" dimensions.  What was a red flag for me was the negative margin on the grid (this is why it will be allowed to overlap your textboxes).

I tend to use multiple grids nested within each other to create what you're looking to do. Think of it from the largest container to the smallest.  For example, there is no reason for your main grid to have 6 columns... it only needs 1 column, but 2 rows to fit your "sections".  The larger section needs 3 sections side-by-side (80%/border/20%) (columns) and 2 sections in the left-most section (grid/border)  Here is an example of what I think you're trying to accomplish.  I left a number of the hard-coded heights and such, as I'm not privy to your requirements, but left off enough to make it responsive.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- I created this grid, because soon I will put image to the left, as my logo, and few informations also, thats reason why I have column definition -->
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Reserved header space-->
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <!--Rest of space for textboxes and grid, etc.-->
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--header section-->
    <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" />

    <!-- This is big grid which is separated in two columns which fits on screen 80% of screen - left part 20% of screen right part -->
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Reserved 80% of remaining space for text/grid-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
            <!--This is the space allowed for the right border-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <!--This is the 20% of remaining space-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--left-hand grid-->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!--Space for Textboxes - left to auto so that it is not overconstrained, but does
            not take up too much space-->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <!--Datagrid gets the remainder of the space-->
                <RowDefinition />
                <!--This is the space allowed for the bottom border-->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--textbox section-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0 5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Height="40" Margin="15,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="1" />
                <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
                <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
                <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
                <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
                <TextBox Height="40"  Margin="0,0,8,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Background="White" BorderBrush="#0091EA" BorderThickness="1" />
            </Grid>
            <!--grid element-->
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="200" Margin="15,0,8,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="White" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
            </DataGrid>


            <!--bottom border element-->
            <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" Height="3" Grid.Row="2" />
        </Grid>
        <!--right border element-->
        <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" Width="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
        <!--right-hand grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
            <!--Whatever content ends up here-->
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

UPDATE:
Here is the final product based on the image you included.  At this point, it is just reviewing the different pieces that were used to put it together and practice that will get it to all come together for you.  Subdivide into logical sections, then work within those sections when you need to manipulate the layout.  If you found this helpful, please feel free to mark as answer and good luck with your application!

```
<!--header section-->
<Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" />
<Grid Height="50" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6 0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="135" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" >
        <TextBlock  x:Name="lblTimeText" Text="Time" />
        <TextBlock  x:Name="lblTime" Text="labelTime" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" >
        <TextBlock  Name="lblDateText" Text="Date" />
        <TextBlock  Name="lblDate"  Text="labelaDate" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" >
        <TextBlock  x:Name="lblOperater"  Text="User" />
        <TextBlock  x:Name="lblOperaterText" Text="Tony Montana" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
        <TextBlock  x:Name="lblBrojRacuna"  Text="Ordinal number." />
        <TextBlock  x:Name="lblBrojRacunaText" Text="0014" FontSize="16" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

<!-- This is big grid which is separated in two columns which fits on screen 80% of screen - left part 20% of screen right part -->
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--Reserved 80% of remaining space for text/grid-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
        <!--This is the space allowed for the right border-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!--This is the 20% of remaining space-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--left-hand grid-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Space for Textboxes - left to auto so that it is not overconstrained, 
            but does not take up too much space-->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <!--Datagrid gets the remainder of the space-->
            <RowDefinition />
            <!--This is the space allowed for the bottom border-->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <!--This is the space allowed for the copyright-->
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--textbox section-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="15 5">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 8 0" />
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0091EA" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="TextBox" FontSize="20" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="TextBox" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="TextBox" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="TextBox" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="TextBox" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="TextBox" />
        </Grid>
        <!--grid element-->
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="200" Margin="15,0,8,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="White" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
        <!--bottom border element-->
        <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" Height="3" Grid.Row="2" />
        <!--copyright-->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Copyright some holder ####" />
    </Grid>
    <!--right border element-->
    <Rectangle Fill="#0091EA" Width="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
    <!--right-hand grid-->
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <!--Whatever content ends up here-->
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I will check this soon, but I dont want text boxes to go over blue line to the right, there I will put something else :)

Comment: I just updated and added comments regarding the column/row definitions.

Comment: check for edit of my question I achieved something can you tell me is it ok, and I have one more question for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I would like to ask you few things on a chat but I dont know how to create one room to keep discuss there, because I learned a lot from your posts/answer and really appreciate that! Now I continued developing this, but I have 2 questions for you, but I wouldn't like to keep it here, lets close this question, so could I contact you somehow mate?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise looking into using stackpanels and dockpanels. Stackpanels have generally been more useful to me in my WPF experience. Also for headers and stuff near the top of the page use fixed spacing instead of calculated percentages based on screen size. I find it's generally better to keep menu bars at a fixed size and let the content be dynamic size.